# Troubles with unity on opening Visual Studio, infinite progress bar

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

As you can see, the progress bar seems to be on an infinity, but Visual Studio works good. This progress bar is always on a display and I can't make it dissapear.
[image: Infinite progress bar Image]

Comment: I've seen this when I try and edit a script without having the solution already loaded in Visual Studio. I just cancel, open the solution, then find the script I wanted to look at.

Comment: I’ve only seen this when it thought there should be a dialogue box pop up